# Find monthly plane/aircraft usage from the nycflights13 data set

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to find the monthly usage of all the aircrafts(based on tailnum)
lets say this is required for some kind of maintenance activity that needs to be done after x number of trips.

As of now i am doing it like below;

```
library(nycflights13)
    N14228  <- filter(flights,tailnum=="N14228")
    by_month <- group_by(N14228 ,month)
    usage <- summarise(by_month,freq = n())
    freq_by_months<- arrange(usage, desc(freq))
```

This has to be done for all aircrafts and for that the above approach wont work as there are 4044 distinct tailnums

I went through the dplyr vignette and found an example that comes very close to this but it is aimed at finding overall delays as shown below

```
    flights %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  select(arr_delay, dep_delay) %>%
  summarise(
    arr = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE),
    dep = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  filter(arr > 30 | dep > 30)
```

Apart from this i tried using aggregate and apply but couldnt get the desired results.

Comment: Isn't this just `flights %>% 
  group_by(tailnum, month) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) %>%
  arrange(tailnum, freq)`? You also don't need all these Intermediate steps, you can just use `%>%`

Comment: Thx david tht solved it, have to do some analysis post this which would consider the usage by month for year 2013 as the ideal, then we would compare the present usage with the ideal usage and would raise a flag in case the present usage is (+some tolerance)  as  compared to the ideal usage given by the above code.
eg. lets say the present month is January and the ideal usage of N14228 should be 15 but in case the the present usage is more than this then there should be a warning saying ideal usage exceeded or close to exceeding ideal usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
flt <- data.table(flights)
flt[, .N, by = c("tailnum", "month")]
       tailnum month  N
    1:  N14228     1 15
    2:  N24211     1 14
    3:  N619AA     1  1
    4:  N804JB     1 29
    5:  N668DN     1  4
   ---                 
37984:  N225WN     9  1
37985:  N528AS     9  1
37986:  N3KRAA     9  1
37987:  N841MH     9  1
37988:  N924FJ     9  1
```

Here, the `.N` means "count occurrence of".

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but regardless, for these kinds of counts, it's hard to beat `data.table` for execution speed and syntactical simplicity.

Comment: Thx Alexey for introducing me to a new way of getting this kind of tasks done, working on further analysis now,thx buddy.